# Large amounts of English text needed

Tags: american-english, british-english, online-resources

I must admit that I'm unsure whether or not this is the right forum for this question. It may belong to statistics and AI also. If there exists a more suitable forum, then tell me.

The thing is, I want to analyse a lot of English text for an AI project ([Confabulation theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540496033)). Is there an online collection of freely available English texts? Books, news would be preferred — scientific texts will properly not do, due to large amounts of math etc.

Comment: Lorem Ipsum placeholder text? (Used quite often for design mockups.) Not English though, but it could work.

Comment: @JFW It won't :/ I need proper English text.

Comment: AI has been closed down, but I'll ask around if this would be on-topic on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/). **Update:** it would be indeed welcome there, especially if you don't want to limit the discussion to simply *obtaining* the data. However, if a) our community deems the question as it is on-topic for our site and b) you are actually satisfied with the quality of answers you're getting here, then of course there's no real need for migration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Main_Page) contains more than 33000 classic books for free, downloadable in different formats.

Also, look at the affiliates sites, where you can find even more books.

EDIT: you may try to contact them to see if there is a way for you to download the books "painlessly" (e.g. with an automated script). I would suggest you ask permission before trying to download all those books automatically. Also, consider making a donation if you end up using their data.

EDIT2: here are the [instructions for accessing the site with a robot](http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Gutenberg%3aInformation_About_Robot_Access_to_our_Pages).

Comment: Thanks :) This link is suitable for robots: http://www.gutenberg.org/robot/harvest

Comment: Good, I'll edit my answer

Comment: @mmeyers: thanks for the edit... I always misspell his name :P

Comment: Project Gutenberg have created several CDs and DVDs available via torrent/ftp/http/etc for easy download: [The CD and DVD Project](http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Gutenberg:The_CD_and_DVD_Project).

Answer (score 6):

Project Gutenberg is a poor choice if you are looking for contemporary language, as most of the PG texts are from the early 20th century and earlier. For large samples of more recent text, you want one of the many available [text corpora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_corpus), such as the following:

- [American National Corpus](http://www.anc.org)
- [British National Corpus](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/)
- [Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://www.americancorpus.org/)
- [The Oxford English Corpus](http://oxforddictionaries.com/page/oec)

Some corpora require a fee for access, and others are free to use. Consult each Web site for specifics.

Answer (score 2):

If n-grams are fine (i.e., you don't need complete sentences and such), you could also try the [Google n-grams dataset](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/datasets).

Answer (score 1):

The Gutenberg project has a specific page for getting offline dumps efficiently - [Information About Robot Access to our Pages](http://www.gutenberg.org/wiki/Gutenberg%3aInformation_About_Robot_Access_to_our_Pages)

Answer (score 0):

And for modern texts, there are a lot of blogs which use various Creative Commons licenses, most commonly CC BY-SA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Wikipedia and the Internet.